# How to remove section name from frametitle header in cambrigeus style

Tags: beamer, sectioning, header-footer

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}
 \mode<presentation> {
 \usetheme{CambridgeUS}
 \usecolortheme{dolphin}
 \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} 
}
 \usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
 \usepackage{booktabs}  
  \section{Motivation} 
  \section{Introduction} 
 \section{State of the Art Development} 
 \section{Problem Statement} 
 \section{References}    

 \begin{frame}
 \frametitle{Motivation}
   \begin{itemize}
   \item 3.4 billion   smart-phone shipped worldwide [1].
   \item Pervasive usage of mobile devices has  enabled  fast growth of mobile applications.
   \item  Mobile devices  have increasing CPU speed and memory size, are not as capable as modern  desktop computers when running applications.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}

\frametitle{Introduction}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Computation offloading is a procedure that migrates resource-intensive computations from a mobile device to the resource-rich cloud, or server (called nearby infrastructure)[2].
  \item An integration of cloud computing technology with mobile devices to make the mobile devices resource full in terms of computational power, memory, storage and energy[3]
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

I am using cambridgeUS style .On every page last section name is shown.I don't want on every slide section name to be represented .For example last section name reference is shown on every slide .I want to remove it.Kindly help me in this regard .Googled alot in this context.
Thanx

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's nice that you included a code example in your first question, but it's not complete. `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` are missing and `\section` commands are misplaced inside your code.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way could be to use `\section[]{Motivation}` because this empty optional parameter is what is shown in frame header. Section name will still be used in table of contents. Similar solution can be adopted with `\subsection` commands.

[image]